# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running python3.7.4 Shell program under tensorflow. When I input sess = tf.Session(),the command line prompt me that module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
this is the message :
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    sess = tf.Session()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

> > >
> >     "

plz help

Answer (score 2):

You must be using tensorflow 2, which does not use session anymore but rather greedy execution. Please refer to their [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf) for more information.

Alternatively, there is a backward compatibility module: [tensorflow.compat.v1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1) you can use like so:

```
>>> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
>>> tf.Session()
```

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you running? `pip list | grep tensorflow`